# Communication between 2 ViewController via Protocol

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, protocols

From the AppDelegate I'm communicating with MyViewController via a Protocol. So when this method gets called in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)thisMethodGetsCalled:(CustomData *)data {
     //Do stuff

     //Then call method via Protocol
     [_exampleDelegate exampleMethod:data];
}
```

It calls this method in MyViewController.m

```
- (void)thisMethodGetsCalledInsideViewController:(CustomData *)data {
     //Do stuff with data
}


//ExampleDelegate.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol SMMessageDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)thisMethodGetsCalledInsideViewController:(CustomData *)data;

@end
```

Everything works fine and as predicted "thisMethodGetsCalledInsideViewController" gets called after "thisMethodGetsCalled". Say MyViewController has never been instantiated then "thisMethodGetsCalledInsideViewController" never gets called. However MyViewController is instantiated and later dismissed with:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

my app crashes when "thisMethodGetsCalled" is called. It tries to call "thisMethodGetsCalledInsideViewController" but that method resides inside MyViewController which is dismissed. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: smell like its ARC enabled?

Comment: it is. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thought:
Somewhere you're setting MyViewController as the delegate of the object that it conforms to the protocol of?
You have to either:

1. set the delegate value to nil when MyViewController is dismissed, or
2. set the delegate property to be a weak reference, i.e.

`@property (nonatomic,assign) id<TheProtocol> delegate;`

Hope that helps.

Comment: my delegate property already was weak just exactly as you're code.

@property (nonatomic, assign) id  _messageDelegate;

but setting the delegate value to nil solved it